# If I am sorting a sequence using the functional paradigm, isn't making copies wasteful?

Tags: python, functional-programming

**Goal**: sorting a sequence in a functional way without using builtin `sorted(..)` function.

```
def my_sorted(seq):
    """returns an iterator"""
    pass
```

**Motivation**: In the FP way, I am constrained:

- never mutate `seq` (which could be an iterator or a realized list)
- By implication, no in-place sorting.

**Question 1** Since I cannot mutate `seq`, I would need to maintain a separate mutable data structure to store the sorted sequence. That seems wasteful compared to an in-place `list.sort()`. How do other functional programming languages handle this ?

**Question 2** If I return a mutable sequence, it that ok in the functional paradigm?

Answer (score 1):

Of course sorting cannot be totally lazy (the last element of input could be the first on output) but you could implement a computational lazy sort that after reading the whole sequence only generates exact sorted output on request element-by-element. You can also delay reading input until at least one output is requested so sorting and ignoring the result will require no computation.

For this computationally lazy approach the best candidate I know is the heapsort algorithm (you only do the heap-building step upfront).

Answer (score 1):

Mutation in-place is only safe if no one else has references to the data, expecting it to be as it was prior to the sort. So it isn't really wasteful to have a new structure for the sorted results, in general. The in-place optimization is only safe if you're using the data in a [linear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_type) fashion.

So, just allocate a new structure, since that is more generally useful. The in-place version is a special case.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate defensive programming *is* wasteful at times, but there's also nothing you can do about it.

This is why languages built to support functional use from the ground up use structural sharing for their natively immutable types; programming in a functional style in a language which isn't built for it (such as Python) isn't going to be as well-supported as a matter of course. That said, a sort operation isn't necessarily a good candidate for structural sharing (if more than minor changes need to be made).

As such, there often *is* at least one copy operation involved in a sort, even in other functional languages. Clojure, for instance, delegates to Java's native (highly optimized) sort operation on a temporary mutable array, and returns a seq wrapping that array (and thus making the result just as immutible as the input which was used to populate same). If the inputs are immutible, and the outputs are immutible, and what happens inbetween isn't visible to the outside world (particularly, to any other thread), transient mutability is often a necessary and appropriate thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use a sorting algorithm that can be performed in a manner that creates a new datastructure, such as heapsort or mergesort.

Answer (score 0):

Wasteful of what? bits? electricity? wall-clock time? A parallel merge-sort may be the quickest to complete if you have enough cpus and a large amount of data, but may produce many intermediary representations.

In general, parallelising an algorithm may lead to a very different optimisation strategy than a serial algorithm. For instance, due to Amdahl's Law, re-performing redundant work locally to avoid sharing. This may be considered "wasteful" in a serial context, but leads to a much more scalable algorithm.